# How to use polarity score to give rating for review text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sentiment-analysis

Currently, I am working in python Textblob to generate the rating for review Text 
 and by using polarity score I am able to get the polarity score (a float) between -1 to 1 for a text like below

```
blob.sentiment.polarity
```

Now I want the rating from 0 to 5 (integer). I am stuck with that how to make polarity score from -1 to 1 to 0 to 5 or any other better approach for doing this to generate the rating.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me check the problem: you have a continuous range over [-1, 1], and you want to translate that to an integer in the range [0, 5] ?

Comment: @Prune ha yes exactly what I want any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a range of [-1, 1] to transform to intervals you can convert to the integers 0 through 5.  This second range can be represented as [0, 6).  Do this in two steps:

Linear transformation: the "stretch and shift" ...

```
new = (old + 1) * 2.999999999999    # stretch the 2-unit interval to nearly 6, shift right one unit.
new = int(new)         # truncate each value
```

Or do this in one step:

```
new = int((old + 1) * 2.999999999999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this simple math,

1. `new = (old + 1)` and now the range is between `[0-2]`
2. Divide it by 2. Range is now between `[0-1]`
3. Multiply it by 5. Range is now `[0-5]`

i.e, `new = (old + 1) * 5 / 2`